# Uninstalling Linux from external hard drive

Tags: linux, external-hdd, uninstall

I have installed Linux 20.04 on my external hard drive and now I want to uninstall it.

How do I go about it?

Comment: We might need more details as to why you are having issues "uninstalling". Also, why not just wipe the hard disk and/or reinstall something else? Is it dual boot? Do you need to preserve any data and/or partitions? Also what is "Linux 20.04"? What *flavour* of Linux? Please [edit] your question and update it with more details - do not add the details in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you would like to do with the hard drive. I’m assuming that you would like to just use it as an external hard drive again. In which case, you should identify it’s device block device with `fdisk -l`, and look for your external hard drive (you should not be booted into it for these steps). Then run `fdisk /dev/sdX` where `X` is the device label found above, then delete the current partitions on the device. Once all the partitions have been deleted, press `n` to create a new partition and press enter through the default values. Then press `w` to write those changes to the disk. Then run `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX1` to create a new filesystem on the hard drive. You can then mount and use it like an actual hard drive.

Hopefully this helps!